# login to facebook api

Tags: java, php, facebook

I have facebook java api. Using this how can I login if i have email and password?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Java : http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/01/facebook-java-apieng.html
- PHP: http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/facebook/facebook-php-tutorial/

**Update:**

For authentification, you can look how to use oauth 2.0:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

You can use the facebook-java-webapp for that:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-webapp/#OAuth_v2

Comment: dude, there is no login method there. instead it redirects to facebook login page.